# How do I extend a length of aluminum flex vent hose?

Tags: bathroom, vent, exhaust-fan, hose

I'm replacing a bathroom ceiling fan, and need to add a short extension (approximately 18") to the length of the existing vent hose.  The existing hose is 4" aluminum flex.

I have a couple questions.  First, would it be acceptable to use the softer foil flex for the extension?  The added flexibility would be nice during installation, and since it is a fan vent and not a dryer vent I assume the fire risk isn't an issue.

Secondly, what's the best way to attach and seal the connection?  Screws, tape, hose clamp, etc?  Ideally it would be something that I could install in tight quarters to avoid having to open another section of drywall--although I'd definetely prefer a good connection over the installation convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a coupling tape and hose clamps.  You use thin flex aluminum duct like shown in picture but I like to stick with the semi rigid flex duct. Zip ties can be used on thin stuff but not semi rigid.

[image]

Comment: Cool, I haven't seen those before